# How to replicate the CAPTUREBLT behavior with Windows Graphics Capture API CreateForWindow(hWnd)

Tags: windows, winapi, screen-capture, direct3d11, bitblt

I am trying to capture a window with Windows Graphics Capture API by getting GraphicsCaptureItem from CreateForWindow and it is working fine. But I have trouble capturing the tooltips of that window if I hover on the menu dropdown is not captured even clicking on the menu dropdown is not captured.
The same can be achieved with BitBlt by providing CAPTUREBLT flag while capturing. Do we have a way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: As I understand, the `GraphicsCaptureItem` associated with a window represents the rendering surface for that window only. It is later used by the DWM to compose the final desktop by layering the individual surfaces on top of each other. To get a fully composed rendering, you would need to create a capture item for a display rather than a window. This, however, would no longer allow you to capture parts of a window obscured by other windows.

Comment: @IInspectable  Yes is the problem.  I want to capture the window along with all the menu dropdowns and tooltips which seems impossible with GraphicsCaptureItem for a window.

Comment: If indeed `Windows.Graphics.Capture` doesn't provide a way to easily capture the fully composed window contents, the workaround would be to enumerate all owned windows, capture each one individually, and manually compose the captures into a final image.

Comment: Will it be possible to do all this in GPU? I want to minimize the load on CPU.

Comment: It makes no sense to want to "optimize" a solution before it even exists. That aside, I would expect that you can keep all Direct3D surfaces in GPU memory.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried capturing owned windows but CreateForWindow is throwing an exception(The parameter is incorrect) for menu dropdowns.